# Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js and I am fairly new to web development in general. I'm trying to have the divs rendered that are in the `componentDidMount` method but they aren't being rendered and I am getting the warning message "Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return". Also, when I `console.log(this.state)` it's only showing an empty object and so `this.state.renderedStreamingLinks` is never being set. I even tried putting `this.setState` inside of `setTimeout` just to see if it's an asynchronous problem going on, but that didn't work either so I am not really sure how to go about solving this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let renderedStreamingLinks = this.props.streamingLinks.map(streamingLink => {
        fetch(streamingLink.relationships.streamer.links.related)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            return(
                <div key={streamingLink.id}>
                    {data.data.attributes.siteName}
                </div>
            )
        })
    })
    this.setState({renderedStreamingLinks: renderedStreamingLinks})
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.renderedStreamingLinks ? this.state.renderedStreamingLinks : ""}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `renderedStreamingLinks`, is async, meaning the `this.setState` will get fired before you have even got the result.  place your setState in your last `then` callback.

Comment: When you call `.map()`, you're supposed to return something. Instead of `streamingLink => {fetch...;}`, try `streamingLink => fetch` or `streamingLink => { return fetch...; }`

Answer (score 0):

The resulting return of `.then()` is a promise. Ie, its a "promise" that something will happen or fail. Theres no "real value" being returned. How to manage promise callbacks is to do the assignment when and where the value is actually obtained, inside the callback. And, your hunch is right, there is an async problem going on.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let renderedStreamingLinks = this.props.streamingLinks.map(streamingLink => {
        fetch(streamingLink.relationships.streamer.links.related)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            const renderedStreamingLinks = (
                <div key={streamingLink.id}>
                    {data.data.attributes.siteName}
                </div>
            );
            this.setState({renderedStreamingLinks: renderedStreamingLinks})
        })
    })

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.renderedStreamingLinks ? this.state.renderedStreamingLinks : ""}
        </div>
    )
}
```